# Oracle NLS_SORT not working via ALTER SESSION?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, sqlplus, globalization

Using 'alter session set nls_sort' does not seem to be working for me. I am using SQLPlus v11.2.0.3.0 x64 and trying to apply the simple steps for 'Example 9-10 NLS_SORT Affects Linguistic Sort Order' found in the Oracle documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_globalization.htm#CACJEJIB

```
CREATE TABLE temp (name VARCHAR2(15));

INSERT INTO temp (name) VALUES ('laguna');
INSERT INTO temp (name) VALUES ('llama');
INSERT INTO temp (name) VALUES ('loco');

SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_SORT';
Result: BINARY

SELECT * FROM temp ORDER BY name;
Result:
NAME
---------------
laguna
llama
loco

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=SPANISH_M;
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_SORT';
Result: SPANISH_M

SELECT * FROM temp ORDER BY name;
Results are the same:
NAME
---------------
laguna
llama
loco
```

According to the doco, the sort order above should have changed but it did not.  But, if I apply the NLS_SORT as part of the query itself I get the correct resutls:

```
SELECT * FROM temp ORDER BY NLSSORT(name, 'NLS_SORT=SPANISH_M');
Result:
NAME
---------------
laguna
loco
llama
```

What am I missing here?  Thx in advance.

Comment: This is a weird problem.  I can't reproduce it, either on my machine or on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35901/7).  Maybe you're hitting some weird bug.  Do you get the same issue with different clients?  You may want to post your client and database version, as well as the results from `select name, value from v$parameter where name like '%nls%';`.

Comment: I can neither reproduce it. I tried it in SQLPlus and SQLDeveloper. It should really work. My version is `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0`.

Comment: I got it to work using 11.2.0.2.0 also.  Odd thing, it works fine for one coworker using 11.2.0.3.0 but not for another.  I will attempt to uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: What exactly are the differences between the environments that work and the environments that don't?  Is this just a difference in clients, or are the problems on different servers?  If it's a server issue, this is a long-shot but you may want to check into Oracle Locale Builder.  Every imaginable NLS setting is configurable.  It's *possible* that one server has a custom, broken version of SPANISH_M.  If you load the linguistic sort and look at the Unicode Collation Sequence, you'll see how the LL and L sort is implemented.  It might give you some idea about how to further troubleshoot.

Comment: nls_language  AMERICAN
nls_territory  AMERICA
nls_sort   BINARY
nls_date_language  AMERICAN
nls_date_format  DD-MON-RR
nls_currency  $
nls_numeric_characters .,
nls_iso_currency  AMERICA
nls_calendar  GREGORIAN
nls_time_format  HH.MI.SSXFF AM
nls_timestamp_format DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
nls_time_tz_format  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
nls_timestamp_tz_format DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
nls_dual_currency  $
nls_comp   BINARY
nls_length_semantics BYTE
nls_nchar_conv_excp FALSE

Comment: Interesting to note, if I change the NLS_SORT to SPANISH_M _**before**_ creating the table and adding the data, then it sorts correctly for Spanish.  And then the subsequent change of NLS_SORT to BINARY has no effect.  I don't have access to the system with the same version as mine with different results today, will look tomorrow.  In any case my DBA assures me that Oracle 12.C does not exhibit this problem and that we will be moving to that for our product release anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved whe I uninstalled Oracle v11.2.0.3.0 and installed v12.1.0.1.0.  Truth be told, I can't rule out that it may have just been a problem with our wrapper/configuration of the v11.2.0.3.0 Oracle installer or Oracle itself.  Thx for all the post just the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
1) Go to the REGISTRY (run regedit)
2) Find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/ORACLE
3) Change NLS_LANG
```

I changed it to

```
AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256
```

dont forget that you must change all the NLS_LANG in part 2.
now you can login to your database and test it.

Comment: While this may provide the correct results it does not solve the problem at the individual session level.  Our application changes the NLS_SORT for the oracle connection/session based upon the user's current locale.